# fatal error two table view in UIview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

in my app i want to display two table view in an UIViewController but i've a fatal error : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

can someone help me about this?

here is the full code of the uiview

> class MyPropertiesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

```
//table view extended
@IBOutlet weak var extandedTableViex: UITableView!

// table view standart
@IBOutlet weak var standartTableView: UITableView!
//list of data
let stdlist = ["1","2","3", "4","5","6","7","8","9"]

let Extlist = ["E1","E2" ]
```

//cell indentifier
    let stdcellIdentifier = "stdcell"

```
let extcellIdentifier = "extcell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    standartTableView.delegate = self
    standartTableView.dataSource = self

    standartTableView.delegate = self
    standartTableView.dataSource = self

    standartTableView.scrollEnabled = false
    extandedTableViex.scrollEnabled = false

    self.standartTableView.registerClass(GuaranteeCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: stdcellIdentifier)
    self.extandedTableViex.registerClass(GuaranteeCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: extcellIdentifier)
}

//count cell
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == standartTableView {
        return self.stdlist.count;
    } else {
        return self.Extlist.count;
    }

}

// add cell
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == standartTableView {
        let cell:GuaranteeCell = self.standartTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(stdcellIdentifier) as! GuaranteeCell
        print("list-element " + self.stdlist[indexPath.row])
           print(indexPath.row)

        cell.guaranteeLabel.text = self.stdlist[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell2:GuaranteeCell = self.extandedTableViex.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(extcellIdentifier) as! GuaranteeCell
        cell2.guaranteeLabel.text = String(self.Extlist[indexPath.row])
        return cell2  
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { }

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

thanks

Comment: Try moving the viewDidLoad code which is written to register for tableViewcell to viewWillAppear method and try

Comment: Are both those table views correctly hooked up in your Storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your cell class is really GuaranteeCell (probably the error is there)

Comment: i've checked and my cell for both tableview is guaranteeCell